# Como eu listo as packages no oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Como eu faço uma query(PL/SQL) para listar uma Package específica existentes no banco(Oracle)?

Comment: Listar todos objetos de uma package ou todos os objetos que são packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para listar todos os packages:

```
SELECT   object_name
FROM     user_objects
WHERE    object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Para verificar se um package específico existe:

```
SELECT   object_name
FROM     user_objects
WHERE    object_type = 'PACKAGE'
    AND  object_name = 'NomeDoPackage'
```

Comment: A que lista todos os packages funciona, porem a que deveria trazer o package específico não funciona.

Comment: @pnet minha primeira suspeita seria que você não possui acesso ao package em questão, ou o nome está ligeiramente diferente (ou em um case diferente, se sua instância do Oracle estiver fazendo comparação case-sensitive).

Comment: Eu clico no package e copio seu nome e quando eu colo na query ele(nome) fica todo em caixa baixa. Dei um upper() e isso resolveu, ou seja, é Case Sensitive. Mas já marquei a resposta. Valeu e obrigado.

Comment: @pnet não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score -2):

Antes tarde do que nunca rsrs

```
select text from dba_source where owner = 'OWNER' AND name = 'PACKAGENAME';
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).